# Assembly code loops one too many times

Tags: assembly, boot, osdev

I'm new to assembly and OS Development w/ the BIOS. I'm currently following a tutorial to help me better know my system and I'm having a looping problem with my code.

Attempting to print out a string with a function (print.asm):

```
print:
    lp:
    mov ax, [bx]    ;Move contents of address in BX into AX
    cmp ax, 00      ;Compare AX to 0
    je jumptrm      ;IF AX == 0 jump to end
    jmp jumppr      ;ELSE print char

    jumppr:         ;Print
    pusha           ;Store current instructions
    mov ah, 0x0e    ;Set to print mode
    mov al, [bx]    ;Set AL to char
    int 0x10        ;Print
    popa            ;Bring back instructions
    add bx, 1       ;Add one to address
    jmp lp          ;Loop

    jumptrm:        ;End
    ret
```

After running it like so (boot.asm):

```
[org 0x7c00]
mov bx, hello
call print
jmp $
%include "print.asm"
hello:
    db 'Hiy', 00
mmph:
    db 'mmph!', 00
times  510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

I keep getting the output:

```
Hiy mmph!
```

Instead of just:

```
Hiy
```

Can anyone lend an extra pair of eyes please?

I'm running my code on Bochs on floppy a if that helps anyone.

Comment: use `al` register to read char and check for `0` bacause in case of `ax` you read two bytes. One byte past the null terminating character may not be zero

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem :)